# centralized logging wrapper for microservices

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, error-handling, microservices

I have spring boot microservices,I use sl4j logger factory and in each service I log messages as follows:

LOG error during an exception:

```
LOG.error("service:{};msg:{};ex:{}", serviceName, msg, ex.getMessage(), ex);
```

LOG error during validation:

```
LOG.error("service:{};msg:{}", serviceName, msg);
```

LOG information:

```
LOG.info("service:{};event:{};msg:{}", service, event, message);
```

This is common in all my microservices, centralise this logging messages using a wrapper or so ? Or put the wrapper in a separate maven application and add dependency as jar ?

I want to know what the best design could be, code snippets will help.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's a good idea to separate concerns, domain logic from infrastructure.

For instance, if you deploy your service as an AWS Lambda, you can see it as a kind of deployment.

Then you should create a separate Maven module where just your Lambda handler's code is located. Further, you can have a module for an Azure Function or a Spring Boot application. You can glue them together with help of Spring Context.

Your logging, mentioned above, would then be a part of your deployment module, because the domain shouldn't know anything about "services".

If your error handling is complicated, you can create a lib module for it.

Example for AWS Lambda:

```
public class Hello implements RequestHandler<Object, String> {
    private DomainLogic domain;
    private ErrorHandling errHandling;

    Hello(DomainLogic domain, ErrorHandling errHandling) {
        this.domain = domain;
        this.errHandling = errHandling;
    }

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(Object input, Context context) {
        try {
           return domain.sayHello(input);
        }
        catch  (Exception e) {
            errHandling.handle(e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```